# Java paintComponent | Graphics g

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paintcomponent

I need help with the paintComponent it dosent work and please help :( ps: I have all the imports...

```
public JavaGame() {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Java Game");
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 20, 20);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
            new JavaGame();
}
```

Comment: Another reason to use `@Override` whenever you *think* that you should be overriding a key method.

Answer (score 3):

JFrame is not a `JComponent`, it doesn't have a `paintComponent` method that can overriden. (Add the `@Override` annotation to see this)

Also it should be

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Move the `paintComponent` method to a new class that extends `JComponent`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: (Nit pick) Personally, *"Do you know that paintComponent is not overridden by the JFrame class"* doesn't read well, I think something more along the lines of "`JFrame` doesn't have a method called `paintComponent` - therefore yours will never be called" might read a little better - IMHO.  +1 none the less

Answer (score 2):

JFrame only has a `paintComponents()` method inherited from the `java.awt.Container` class, but a JPanel has the `paintComponent()` method inherited from the `javax.swing.JComponent` class. You want to use the latter to draw most of the time, but your `JavaGame` class is a JFrame subclass. I'd recommend you add a JPanel to the JFrame and draw on the label by overriding paintComponent().

Comment: You're on the right track, but personally, I wouldn't bother with `JLabel`, it carries to many other requirements.  I would, personally, use a `JPanel` as the bases for the application which would allow me to override the `paintComponent` method. I think I can see the reason for your advice, but I think the code presented by the OP is just example code and the `drawString` is just a test - I could be wrong though ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the information. I actually meant JPanel, my fingers just converted my thoughts to keystrokes stupidly.

Comment: How I know the feeling :P